# why is ("") needed when using .split, .reverse, .join

Tags: javascript, string

For example if I˙d use str.split() it wouldn`t work, but when using str.split("") it works normaly.

question may be weird but what does "" actually do? Could you give me some examples where something else is used (if it`˙s even used)? Is it just the syntax or is there a reason?

Hope you understand it, a bit hard to explain.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: The `.split()` function takes one non-optional argument: the substring that breaks up the source string. `""` is just an empty string.

Comment: @CrazyTrain According to MDN it **is** optional, but by default it just returns an array of one element being the original string. `"1,2,3".split()` returns `["1,2,3"]` when I execute it.

Comment: R.T.F.M........

Comment: @Ivar: Sorry, I was wrong. It doesn't use that default. You're right.

Comment: @Ivar well I guess that makes sense; it's kind-of pointless without the separator however :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `split()`, without a delimeter, doesn't really make sense.  `split()` with `""` says "Split between every character".  With anything else, it means "Split into an Array of Strings every time you encounter this character".

For example:

```js
const str = "h1e1l1l1o1w1o1r1l1d";
console.log(str.split(1));
```

This will split into an Array where each letter of "helloworld" is an individual item of the Array.

Additionally, the spec implementation dictates what happens if a **separator** is omitted (emphasis mine):

> Specifies the string which denotes the points at which each split
>   should occur. The `separator` is treated as a string or as a regular
>   expression. If a plain-text `separator` contains more than one
>   character, that entire string must be found to represent a split
>   point. **If `separator` is omitted** or does not occur in `str`, the
>   array returned contains one element consisting of the entire string.
>   If `separator` is an empty string, `str` is converted to an array of
>   characters.

Please read the documentation for the following methods:

- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method accepts two optional parameters, if you pass nothing into the method, it returns an array with the original string as the first value in the array.

First parameter is a character to split on, if this is an empty string, it splits on every character, so if your string variable is dog and you call split on it passing empty string, it would break each character into an array, so you would have an array with 3 elements, each being a letter, array[0] = 'd', array[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) = 'o', array[2] = 'g'

Second parameter is optional and gives a limit as to how many splits to make, so if you had a word that could be split 6 times on whitespace and you passed the second parameter as 5, it would ommit the last portion.

Comment: Don't refer people to w3schools, please.

Comment: So if I understood your comment correctly by using split("") ure splitting a string to single characters, but without it you are splitting it into an multiple arrays?

Comment: @M.Vrh It's always splitting into an array, if you pass "" into split, it splits on each character in the string. So in my comment I gave you an example of how dog would be split into an Array of length 3 each indice holding one letter, if you pass nothing into split(), it still creates an array, but the length is 1 and the value is of the original string